# Ruby on Rails trouble creating record with has_many :through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using rails 3.2.14 and having trouble using has_many :through for the first time. I'm using a has_many :through relationship between Image and Design tables using a Design_Pictures table that will store the order ranking for design images. All Images are associated with one User. Later I want the flexibility to store other images in the Images table that are not associated with a particular design.

I can successfully add sample data to my database and show the image title (which is stored in the images table) and ranking (which is stored in the design_pictures table) in my show design pages. What I can't figure out is how to create a new design_picture. Once I can get this working I'm going to use CarrierWave or Paperclip to add images to the Image table.

Here are my models:

**app/models/image.rb:**

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :design_pictures, dependent: :destroy 
  has_many :designs, :through => :design_pictures

  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :title, length: { maximum: 80 }
end
```

**app/models/design.rb:**

```
class Design < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title
  has_many :design_pictures, dependent: :destroy 
  has_many :images, :through => :design_pictures

  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 60 }
end
```

**app/models/design_picture.rb:**

```
class DesignPicture < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :ranking
  belongs_to :image
  belongs_to :design

  validates :image_id, presence: true
  validates :design_id, presence: true   

  default_scope order: 'design_pictures.ranking ASC'
end
```

**app/models/user.rb:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :designs, dependent: :destroy 
  has_many :images, dependent: :destroy

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
end
```

Views:

**app/views/designs/show.html.erb:**

```
            <div>
                <% if @design.design_pictures.any? %>
                    <h3>Images (<%= @design.design_pictures.count %>)</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <%= render @design_pictures %>
                    </ul>
                <% end %>
            </div>

            <div>
                <%= render 'shared/design_picture_form' %>
            </div>
```

**app/views/design_pictures/_design_picture.html.erb**

```
<li>
    <%= design_picture.image.title %> - Ranking: <%= design_picture.ranking %>
</li>
```

**app/views/shared/_design_picture_form.html.erb:**

```
<%= form_for(@design_picture) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

    <%= f.label :title, "Title" %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, 
                placeholder: "Name your image.",
                class: "" %>

    <%= f.label :ranking, "Ranking" %>
    <%= f.text_field :ranking, 
            placeholder: "Rank your design picture.",
            class: "" %>            

    <%= hidden_field_tag(:design_id, @design.id) %>

    <%= f.submit "Add Image", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Controllers:

**app/controllers/designs_controller.rb**

```
    def show
        @design = Design.find(params[:id])
        @design_pictures = @design.design_pictures.find(:all, :limit => 10)

        @image = current_user.images.build 
        @design_picture = @design.design_pictures.build
    end
```

**app/controllers/design_pictures_controller.rb**

```
    def create
        @current_design = Design.find(params[:design_id])
        @image = current_user.images.new(params[:title])
        @design_picture = @current_design.design_pictures.build(:image_id => @image.id, params[:ranking])

        if @design_picture.save
            flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
            redirect_to @current_design
        else
            redirect_to designs_url
        end
    end
```

Error when I visit the design_picture form partial:

```
undefined method `title' for #<DesignPicture image_id: nil, design_id: 1427, ranking: nil>
```

If I remove the title from the form I can submit form but nothing is created.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about this but this is how I was able to get my form to submit and create both an Image entry with it's title attribute and the Design_Picture entry with it's rank attribute. I ended up not needing to use accepts_nested_attributes_for.

**app/views/shared/_design_picture_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@design_picture) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

<%= label_tag(:title, "Title") %>
<%= text_field_tag(:title) %>   

<%= f.label :ranking, "Ranking" %>
<%= f.text_field :ranking, 
        placeholder: "Rank your design picture.",
        class: "" %>            

<%= hidden_field_tag(:design_id, @design.id) %>

<%= f.submit "Add Image", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
```

**app/controllers/designs_controller.rb**

```
def show
    @design = Design.find(params[:id])
    @design_pictures = @design.design_pictures.find(:all, :limit => 10)

    @design_picture = @design.design_pictures.build
end
```

**app/controllers/design_pictures_controller.rb**

```
def create
    @image = current_user.images.create(:title => params[:title])
    @current_design = Design.find(params[:design_id])       
    @design_picture = @current_design.design_pictures.build(params[:design_picture])
    @design_picture.image_id = @image.id

    if @design_picture.save
        flash[:success] = "Design Picture created!"
        redirect_to @current_design
    else
        redirect_to designs_url
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `DesignPicture` does not have a `title` attribute. When you do:

```
@design.design_pictures.build
```

It build a new `DesignPicture` instance. And the following do not work:

```
<%= form_for(@design_picture) do |f| %>
  # ...

  <%= f.label :title, "Title" %>

  # ...
```

You might want to take a look at [Nested Form](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)

Comment: Since `DesignPicture` belongs to `Image`, how do I get it to use the Image `title` attribute?

Comment: you can access it using `@design_picture.design.title`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the Nested Forms. That is part of my problem. If I take out the title attribute it still does not create anything. I think I have a bigger underlying problem in that I don't understand how to create new records with a has_many :through relationship.

Comment: I'm using nested forms but I think I have something wrong in my controller that is keeping it from having the image title fields. Do you see anything wrong with this: `def show
  @design = Design.find(params[:id])
  @design_pictures = @design.design_pictures.find(:all, :limit => 10)

  @image = current_user.images.build 
  @design_picture = @design.design_pictures.build
 end`

Comment: nothing wrong with that, the `title` attribute exists only on `@design` instance. Not on `@design_picture`. You can see to what an instance reponds using `@design.respond_to?(:title)` and `@design_picture.respond_to?(:title)`

Comment: I have a `title` attribute in both the Design and Image tables. The `title` attribute of Image is the one I'm trying to set. When the form is submitted I need it to create a new Image record with title attribute saved and a new DesignPicture record with ranking attribute saved. Not sure how to set up my controller to allow this.